# Full Strength of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normal-families

We define a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ on a domain $\Omega$ to be equicontinuous if for each point $x \in \Omega$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_x > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $| x - y| < \delta_x$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

Define a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ on a domain $\Omega$ to be *uniformly* equicontinuous if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $| x - y| < \delta$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and for all $x \in \Omega$.

The Arzela-Ascoli theorem is sometimes stated for the second class of families, but in fact it is true for both.  I am reading a book that proves it only for the second, and they make the comment that the full version is almost never needed in applications.  Since this is a complex analysis book I can definitely believe that, but I am wondering if there are any important results that have needed the full strength.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: in my note http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/23.pdf I call the pointwise one EQ1, the other EQ2, and show they are the same for compact metric domains (which is where applications mostly are found). The pointwise one needs no metric in general (just any space), the uniform one needs a uniform space, so the assumptions are quite different.

Comment: What about just a complete separable metric space, as opposed to compact?